# Good Pre-generated adventure for absolute new Players and new DM?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, game-recommendation, new-players, published-adventures, new-gm

Next weekend, I and three friends are going to sit down and have a game of D&D. None of us have ever played D&D before and I have been given the role of DM. I'm looking for a good pre-generated adventure for absolute beginners to get us all into the game and teach us how the game is played.

The adventure should be simple but exciting and I should easily be able to understand what I'm supposed to do and say. The adventure preferably would be free and have any maps needed.

Comment: There are hundreds if not thousands of pregenerated adventures for level 1 characters, available in stores, in PDF, free on the Web - you'll need to narrow this down to be answerable on the site.

Comment: Are you wedded to D&D 3.5e? As you're just starting out, you may be interested to know that the current edition of D&D (5th) has [free basic rules](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules) that may be more approachable for new DMs and players. Alternatively, if you're looking more for *the best* introductory D&D adventure and would use whatever D&D edition fits it, that may change the answers you will get. (And if you're set on D&D 3.5e, then clarifying that will prevent people wasting your time any further with suggestions/questions about changing editions. :)

Comment: I think this is on hold as too broad because people think finding the best free module for a first time GM in D&D 3.5 gming new players which is both free and includes good maps is not yet specific enough.  Consider picking some random other feature you don't actually care about in order to satisfy that desire for specificity.  Perhaps "and includes goblins", or "and includes an ambush", etc.